# For loop to 1) extract and 2) paste to an object, in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have run some data through MCMCglmm to produce 16 chains - they are .rda files each with the following  with a structure looking a little something like this (the list has 16 components, e.g. Sol, VCV, DIC.., I've only posted the top part because it's quite long) and in total there are 16 of these list (one per chain):

```
> dput(lapply(chain_shortA1, function(x) head(x,3))[1])
structure(list(Sol = structure(c(1.04619275548612, 1.05064026996843, 
1.0508443605213, 1.05060001081438, 25.347877898399, 23.9721841898718, 
25.137209308421, 23.7787279045151, 65.739413601812, 63.8638016616824, 
65.9364721911843, 65.2303675767507, -0.133519658555997, -0.140548052135273, 
-0.135612305268296, -0.141013350017602, 29.0450402791412, 29.2720730875153, 
27.966162882396, 28.8481791445811, 50.6246755414177, 49.9310506192269, 
52.2747936783417, 50.0815610028321), .Dim = c(4L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("(Intercept)", "traitcl_f", "traitls_f", "traitbs_m", 
    "traitcl_m", "traitls_m")), mcpar = c(101, 131, 10), class = "mcmc")), .Names = "Sol")
```

I need to extract and store a number of these items for each chain, e.g. for just two chains and two values there are four combinations:

```
chain_shortA1_DIC = chain_shortA1$DIC
chain_shortA1_VCV = chain_shortA1$VCV
chain_shortA2_DIC = chain_shortA2$DIC
chain_shortA2_VCV = chain_shortA2$VCV
```

I think this can be done by first of all providing a list of the chains and values I want:

```
chains = list ("chain_shortA1","chain_shortA2")
values = list ("DIC", "VCV")
```

And then running it through a loop to produce all four items. However, I'm struggling with the loop part (I'm not the most fluent loop writer). This is my current attempt but it doesn't do what I had hoped for:

```
for (i in 1:length(chains)){
    eval( parse( text = paste(chains[i], "$", values[i], sep = "")))
    }
```

As a proof of principle, the script to print the value within the loop *does* work:

```
> eval( parse( text = paste(chains[1], "$", values[1], sep = "")))
[1] 125861.2
```

Furthermore, when I try the following I am also getting problems (each object should be stored as 'chain'_'value' e.g. chain_shortA1_DIC, as above)

```
for (i in 1:length(chains)){
    paste(chains[i],"_",values[i]) = eval( parse( text = paste(chains[i], "$", values[i], sep = "")))
    }
```

*If anything is unclear please comment and I'll edit/respond to clarify*

Comment: If you can `dput` the head of the `chain_shortA1`, it may be easier to test

Comment: @akrun could you expand on that a little - I have no idea what you mean as it stands

Comment: If you run `dput(head(chain_shortA1))` on the console, it will give the structure of the dataset as output.  Copy/pasting that output to your post will make it more easier for others to understand your data and also will serve as an example to test the code.

Comment: @akrun dput() with head produced about 1500 lines in my console - I used dput() with names instead - does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is correct, but it doesn’t store the result anywhere.

But it’s also more complicated than necessary – you don’t need `parse`/`eval` here because `x$y` is equivalent to `x[['y']]`. So you can do this:

```
chains[i][[values[i]]]
```

… and assign the result to some variable:

```
assign(paste(chains[i], values[i], sep = '_'), chains[i][[values[i]]])
```

But I don’t think it’s a great idea to create such variables in the first place: instead of having a variable of the format `chain_shortA1_DIC` you can just as well use a nested list, and this seems to be the original data format you already have to begin with.

---

As an aside, `paste(…, sep = '')` is equivalent to `paste0(…)`. But in your case you even *do* have a separator, because you wrote `paste(…, '$', …, sep ='')`. This works, of course, but the way `paste` is intended to be used is like this: `paste(…, …, sep = '$')`.